# Where to ask question on Android image processing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to calculate where to crop a camera preview in real-time on Android.

What Stack Exchange site is right for that question?

EDIT: It doesn't specifically have to be Android. I'm more interested in how to calculate the crop location on an image (quickly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on-topic for Stack Overflow, if:

1. You show us your current code that attempts to crop the image,
2. What you believe the correct behavior should be, and
3. What the behavior actually is.

Stack Overflow doesn't accept requests for complete solutions;  you are expected to have made a good-faith effort to solve the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Android.StackExchange.com's FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq),

- Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)